# Flutter Gradle Build Error- FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: flutter, gradle

Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not load compiled classes for build file 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\calculator_ui\basics\android\build.gradle' from cache.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 30s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Exited (1).

I have tried flutter doctor but everything is fine